# (Reopened) Where do we draw the line for whether a question is really a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I noticed the question [Colleagues routinely only answer the first of my questions?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/182000/colleagues-routinely-only-answer-the-first-of-my-questions) was closed as a duplicate of the question [I emailed my customer asking multiple questions. Their reply addressed only one. What is the polite way to point this out?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/44483/i-emailed-my-customer-asking-multiple-questions-their-reply-addressed-only-one).

I disagree that they are the same question. They even ask different things based on the way they are worded. The coworkers one is phrased in such a way that asks how to avoid the problem in the first place, whereas the clients one asks what to do after the fact.

Even if they were even closer (e.g. let's say they were both asking how to prevent the problem), there could be small differences that could potentially yield different answer. For example: does it matter that the recipient is a coworker instead of a client? The answer might change just based on this distinction depending on the circumstance.

So in essence, I have two question:

1. Shall we re-open the [Colleagues routinely only answer the first of my questions?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/182000/colleagues-routinely-only-answer-the-first-of-my-questions)?
2. Where do we draw the line?

Comment: Apparently, if they have five words in common.  :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While I agree in your assessment that there's an important distinction between the two questions usually the rule of thumb is not whether the questions themselves are necessarily identical but whether the *answers* of the dupe-target also answer the new question. So is that the case here?

The top-voted answer of the dupe target actually provides something you could argue as direct solution to the new question:

> knowing this is an issue, send 5 different emails if you need answers to 5 different questions. The response really depends on how important to the company this client is.

It does seem like it would be *an* answer to it at the very least, although it would have to be considered a frame challenge to the OP's desire **not** to send multiple separate e-mails. Given that, the differences in the recipients of the e-mails and that the answer the OP of the new question has accepted *isn't* the same and also explicitly addresses the fact the OP is asking about internal e-mails I've re-opened it.

Answer (score 1):

This has been a pet peeve of mine from Day1.

My first question here was about being "Overqualified" and "disabled", and It was shut down as a duplicate because there were questions about being overqualified.  The only problem was is that that wasn't the question I was asking.

[link here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/62205/how-do-i-address-both-being-overqualified-and-unable-to-perform-at-past-levels)

One user tends to think that virtually all posts are duplicates, and We've often voted to reopen.  Not that this one user is convinced.