# I think we can do better at not closing questions in a knee-jerk manner

Tags: discussion

There seems to be a glut of questions closed lately, and my interpretation is that we are not taking into consideration what is effectively the deletion of content of others before casting a close vote.

It literally takes us 2 seconds to vote to close, but several magnitudes more time to answer a question carefully, taking into consideration the provided factors of the question. When we close a question, that content gets hidden from a wide range of users. We're essentially discarding effort of others. I don't think we should do that so much.

I think it's not just us regular users. Moderators themselves can also do this, though obviously their actions have significant more impact. My understanding is that the moderator modus operandi, it to generally let the community self-regulate, but lately I've seen instances where they have forced questions shut, for merely lacking some detail. I think we can all be better at tolerating questions that are inexact.

I think it's important to recognize that TWP means different things to different people. Some incredibly broad questions can actually inspire a range of different responses, which rather that being a prescriptive answer about what exactly the course of action the OP should take, can actually encourage the OP to assess each answer on its merits, looking at the particular assumptions and rationale behind each answer. It's possible the best course of action for a given reader, either the OP, or someone with a similar issue, could be a combination of two answers that are diametrically opposed.

The question is, does a lack of information mean that the question fundamentally cannot be answered. I think it's incredibly rare that a question is lacking in enough detail to make it unanswerable at all.

For some people, questions are meant to be useful for others in the future, rather than just the OP. Some answers given may be particular unsuitable for the OP, but provided that assumptions are qualified, the question can be of great benefit to others.

This is also why I don't think we should close questions that have been answered. I believe they can serve other people.

I believe fundamentally people need to be willing to appreciate that TWP has people that have differing ideas about what TWP is for, and consensus has not been reached on the matter. So I think more acceptance of questions that we think is either lacking detail, or has too much detail is called for.

And am I looking to shift what people consider the purpose of TWP? No. I recognise that some people consider that questions, and their answers, should serve a single person, that being the asker, and only the asker. And that's fine. It's not what I think TWP is for, but this question has come up before, and I know several members of our community (even high ranking ones) think questions should be specific for individuals.

What are your thoughts? Am I seeing close-vote patterns that simply are not there?

Comment: I agree with many question closures I saw. When I didn't, [I created a Meta question about it](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7028/reopened-where-do-we-draw-the-line-for-whether-a-question-is-really-a-duplicat) or [someone else did](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/181900/how-to-find-motivation-to-keep-applying-to-jobs-after-being-rejected). And usually I'm not the only one that thinks the question was closed without warrant.

Answer (score 6):

> I think we can all be better at tolerating questions that are inexact.

This comes up on meta about once a month it seems. My position hasn't changed in the years I've been here: as a *community* we close questions quickly but for the vast majority of posts this is the correct decision, almost always we provide info on why the post was closed, and questions that can be reopened with some edits *are* reopened quickly. The community has also gotten very good at posting on meta when a question needs some TLC or was edited into shape and needs some reopen votes.

In other words, the community and the tools at our disposal are working very well and as intended.

> lately I've seen instances where [moderators] have forced questions shut, for merely lacking some detail.

Isolated instances do not make a pattern, nor do I believe that casting a binding vote when a question is on 2-3 close votes and/or when multiple mods agree with the closure in chat constitutes "forcing it shut". Please reach out to the community team via the contact page if you have issues with our approach to moderation.

Answer (score 1):

Closing isn't the end for a question.

We get a lot of new users here who have pretty unformed questions.  The right thing to do is close them and help the asker workshop their question into a form that is actually constructive for them.

There is no value in making people answer for every single variable that someone doesn't bother to specify. "Here's a big old answer!"  "Oh I'm in the UK, everything you just said is invalidated" is a waste of everyone's time, and people who have their time wasted are less likely to answer questions (or ask more questions). Questions lacking vital details *should* be closed, and closed as quickly as possible to avoid wasting people's time.

What we can get better on isn't not closing questions, but in engaging with querents to help them make the questions better.  Some "pro forma" comments might help along these lines - let's say a question gets closed because it really needs a country tag.  Often a questioner just sees a close, or maybe a close with several comments one of which maybe is asking about a country tag but the others are the usual nattering, answering in comments, etc.  That's a bad user experience.

What we should do is keep comments clean (flag answering in comments and such) and take the extra time to explain to a user "Hey this has been closed/is on its way to being closed because you really need to add X information, or ask it in a way that's not just opinion, or explain something more (or less)"... Then they can change it and get it reopened quickly.

I personally have been reluctant to do this. Mainly because the climate here seems like you just get yelled at by someone else in the comments, or someone takes it to meta and gets the mods to open-hammer the question without improving it, or similar most of the time, which discourages actually improving the questions.

Comment: "Oh I'm in the UK, everything you just said is invalidated" My point is that maybe the answer will be useful to somebody else, who isn't from the UK. Provided it's clear what assumptions have been made, I don't see the harm in answers that may not be exactly accurate for the OP, but may be useful to others with a slightly different scenario.

Comment: If you just want to write a bunch of your own thoughts get a blog.  This format thrives in real answers to real questions, not just spraying info because “surely someone will find it oh so valuable someday.”

Comment: TWP means different things to different people. We keep questions around even after the OP has their answer because we do hope that somebody else will find it oh so valuable someday. I certainly don't write answers to satisfy only the OP.

Comment: And thanks for the suggestion to create a blog. Unfortunately, on reflection, I think my content is more likely to be seen and be useful here on TWP.

Comment: _"Closing isn't the end for a question"_ Realistically though, on _this_ site, it is.

Answer (score 0):

> What are your thoughts? Am I seeing close-vote patterns that simply
> are not there?

I'm not seeing anything new happening.

A question is posted. A few select folks take it upon themselves to very quickly decide that it fails one of the reasons for closing and vote to close. Others see that and follow. For some reason, it seems to make them happy. ("Rules is rules!" ???)

The result is that many quite-salvageable questions get closed. And new members get discouraged. I've given up trying to salvage and re-open most of them.

Personally, I prefer to post comments seeking clarification, in hopes that the question can get some good answers for the person asking, before it gets closed. I think almost everyone who makes an effort to ask a question deserves an answer - even if their question isn't perfectly formed.

While sad, this pattern isn't unusual for a gamified forum. So it goes...

> I think we can do better at not closing questions in a knee-jerk
> manner

I know we could do better. I see no evidence that we will.

Comment: You've been around a while, so you think we can bump up the number of votes required from 5 to 10 or something? Or is that delaying the inevitable?

Comment: @GregoryCurrie - bumping up the required number of votes wouldn't hurt. Not sure it cures anything, but at least a bigger window of opportunity for useful answers to sneak in before the close. I don't know if that is configurable, though. And I don't see any changes being made anyway. Perhaps I'm being too cynical.

Comment: It's definitely configurable: some sites need only three votes to close (e.g. [Software](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9268) and [English](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15007)). I think the bigger obstacle to overcome is the community's perception that there's a problem. It's frustrating because _"I won't answer you and I'll stop anyone else from answering you as well. Come back when you know how to ask a better question"_ would be a completely inappropriate response to getting asked a poorly worded question as a senior colleague in an ___actual workplace___

Comment: @PlayerOne - true. Online forums don't often bring out the best behavior in people.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie I have had a couple of goes at getting the number of votes changed, I'm still working on it whenever I get a chance. Unfortunately it's easier to lower the threshold than increase it at the moment.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere don't be discouraged, I for one have no problem hammering open if the situation warrants it.

Comment: @Kilisi - thanks. Reopening closed questions doesn't really solve the problem for me. Quickly closing sends a bad message to the member writing the question. I'm more resigned to the situation than discouraged. It is what it is.

Comment: Well... we only have two recourses. I'm discarding one which is penalising people over their voting habits. As far as I'm concerned everyone is entitled to their vote within the parameters of the site, no questions asked. Which leaves changing the parameters of the site. That's what I'm trying to do. But frankly only had a specious runaround so far. But I'm a persistent chap ;)